# Devexpress report designer version conflicts

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I'm trying to add a DevExpress Report Desginer Wizard to my WPF project but I keep getting an error about versions. I've posted a screenshot to simplify things

> This project already contains references to DevExpress controls of a different version.
>   The current version is 15.2.4.
>   Incorrect reference: DevExpress.Data.v14.1 14.1.8

I've updated the project files per [the DevExpress Upgrade notes](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#GeneralInformation/CustomDocument2221) but this hasn't changed anything.

[image]

Comment: What if you remove all DevExpress references and then add the new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the error by removing all references to DevExpress components with a different version than the 15.2 that it was trying to use.

I had to clean and build my solution after doing this because they obstinately kept coming back and causing trouble so if you're here looking for a solution, be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute "[upgrade tool](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#ProjectConverter/CustomDocument2529)" from the visual studio menu
DevExpress -> Upgrade tool,
run this tool on the current solution/project, close the wpf window designer, rebuild solution/project, open your wpf window again in the designer, check that the toolbox contains WPF ReportDesigner v15.2 control and add it to the wpf window.